# jQuery: Given just an element ID name, how do it find its position in the dom relative to its parent?

Tags: jquery, traversal

This one has me stumped.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="store"></div>
    <div id="contact"></div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for the contact divs position as child of "container". So just to be extra clear, if i'm looking for 'contact's position, i need jquery to return the number 1.

any help is greatly appreciated!
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
$('#contact').prevAll('div').length + 1
```

as in get the length of previous div siblings. Omit the +1 if you want a zero-based index.

Comment: @nickf - you're right, I initially thought he wanted it to start from 1, but I've just re-read the question based on your comment. Anyway, I have edited.

Comment: Works fantastic and didn't have to leave jquery! perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById("contact");
var i = 0;
while (el.previousSibling != null)
{
   el = el.previousSibling;
   i = i + 1;
}
// i is the index of the item.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe find the parent and iterate through the children until you find the node, counting along the way.

```
function findPos(id) {
  var child = $('#' + id), children = child.parent().children();
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i)
    if (children.get(i) == child) return i;
  throw "makes no sense";
}
```

You could turn that into a jQuery method of course.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var ids = $("#container").children().map(function(n, i) {
    return n.id;
});

var requiredIndex = jQuery.inArray("contact", ids);
```